# Android SecurityException: Permission Deniel for CAMERA permission in the AndroidManifest file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, registerforactivityresult, activity-result-api

I'm using **ActivityResultAPI** for capturing photos in my app so as I'm using this API I can't include CAMERA permission in Manifest file right.

But now in my application there is barcode scanner feature for that I need camera permission to be added into manifest file.

But it gives below exception while using take picture feature but works fine for barcode sacn feature..

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera clip={text/uri-list {...}} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{67b91af 8305:com.ehr.myairmed/u0a422} (pid=8305, uid=10422) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA**

Is there any alternative solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you asked permissions programmatically?

Comment: @JunaidKhalid yes, I've added CAMERA permission in Manifest file and also asked runtime permission using RequestPermission contract. That works fine for me, but if I used image capture feature first before requesting CAMERA permission then the app gets crashed giving above mentioned error.

Comment: Well that is the normal behavior. If the permissions are not given then the app will crash

Comment: @JunaidKhalid no we don't require to add CAMERA permission for TakePicture() contract as per official document